# How to check if value is number in Varnish?

Tags: caching, cookies, varnish, varnish-vcl

Cookie String Example:

```
session=9urt2jipvkq77brfrf; MyId=124 ; PageId=134
```

I'm using Varnish version 4.1. In the following code, I extract the value of `MyId` (124) and `PageId` (134) from the cookie string and then check if the values are the same. If it is, return `pass` and don't serve cache content. The problem is that anonymous visitors will not have these two cookies in place unless they sign up, and it will accidentally pass the condition and not cache because both values will return the same value `session=9urt2jipvkq77brfrf` with the `regsub` function. I want to make sure that both values are entirely number. Is there any function handy for that?

Code:

```
if(req.http.Cookie){

   set req.http.MyId = regsub(req.http.Cookie,".*MyId=(\d+).*","\1");

   set req.http.PageId = regsub(req.http.Cookie,".*PageId=(\d+).*","\1");

   if(req.http.MyId == req.http.PageId){

       return (pass);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a handy function like "is_integer" or similar. But you can check it with regular expressions.

This will match any sequence of numbers:

```
req.http.MyId ~ "[0-9]+"
```

Or you can match only 3 numbers:

```
req.http.MyId ~ "[0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a vmod or inline C.  Here is an inline C example testing a header value:

```
sub vcl_backend_response
{
    // Check some value from your backend server response
    if (beresp.http.X-MyCustom-Header)
    {
      C{
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "Received a X-MyCustom-Header");
        char *val_to_test;
        const struct gethdr_s hdr = { HDR_BERESP, "\022X-MyCustom-Header:" };
        val_to_test = VRT_GetHdr(ctx, &hdr);
        int val_int = atoi(val_to_test);  // or whatever C functions
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "My int value was: %d", val_int);
      }C
   }

   ...
}
```

Normally you would package all of that inline C into a vmod and make your life easier but it can be useful for testing before moving to a vmod.